# Allow access to site B from site A

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js, redirect, single-sign-on

I guess the common term used today is `"Single Sign On"`.

Allow me to explain my situation. Please pardon me if I use the wrong terminology or am unclear with my explanation as I am not a particularly good developer nor an architecture person.

> I have Site A (eg. www.siteA.com) and Site B (eg. www.siteB.com)

Site A is a Java Project, while Site B is an Angular JS + Node JS project (MyEAN Stack).

A link will be provided on Site A to go to Site B. However, you will only be allowed to view the page on Site B after successfully logging in on Site A.

The flow would be.

> 1. Log in on Site A
> 2. Click on link to Site B
> 3. Site B loads

If user attempts to go to www.siteB.com, they will not be allowed access. You must pass through Site A. So the request must come from Site A minimally. SiteB currently does not have a log-in page.

Note:- `The 2 sites are different domains.`

I would like to know where should I start looking to find out how I should implement this. Any form of ideas would be great as I have been reading and reading but haven't found a good place to start. Perhaps I am reading at the wrong place.

Comment: Use JWT (Java Web Tokens) 
After signing in on SiteA. The user will be provided with a token which is passed on to SiteB when the user is redirected to siteB. Normally the token is passed on in Headers. Make sure to have some validation check on your siteB regarding that token.

Comment: Its JWT (JSON Web Tokens) :P my Bad

Comment: Hi @HimanshuBansal sorry but may I know how exactly should we pass it during the redirection? And also how will Site B read the HTTP header ? Sorry but this is absolutely new to me.

Comment: i assume that ur java server redirect the page after login. During the redirection, you can set the headers. Once headers in the new link.. nodejs (using expressjs) can read headers using `req.headers`. you can read more on this link http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html. etc i'll provide the whole process in few hour. :) please wait ^^

Comment: Hi @HimanshuBansal thank you very much for your time. Looking forward to seeing this process.

Comment: Check it.. i have added the process..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JWT (Java Web Tokens) 
After signing in on SiteA. The user will be provided with a token which is passed on to SiteB when the user is redirected to siteB. Normally the token is passed on in Headers.

**Process**:

Once user login to the SiteA. The user is provided with a Token(JWT). When the user click on the link to SiteB, the user is redirected to something like `www.siteA.com/redirect`. The java web server get this request and in response it sends the new link with Token in Header and status code 301.

Note:- Since I am no Java Developer and I have no idea about the kind of Java Server you are using, I am providing the example with express. I hope you get the idea from there.

```
router.get('/redirect', function(req, res) {
    var token = 'jsdh98yuhes87e6ywqy2'; // Something Your server have generated

    res.header('Authorization', token);

    res.redirect(301,'http://www.SiteB.com/autologin/');
});
```

Now the user it at NodeJS Server. All you have to do now is verify the token to verify if the user is redirected from the Java Website(SiteA).

NodeJS server get that request and check for headers.

```
app.get('/autologin', function(request, response) {
    let token = request.headers['Authorization'];
    var isValid = false;
    // Your check logic here
    if(isValid){// If Valid redirect to SiteB
        response.cookie('id_token' ,request.headers['x-auth-token'], { maxAge: 9000,expires: 600}); 
        response.redirect(301,'http://www.siteB.com');
    }else{//If not Valid redirect back to SiteA


        return response.redirect(301, "http://www.siteA.com"); 
    }
});
```

If Token is valid the user can access the website `www.SiteB.com` else the user is redirected back to `www.SiteA.com`.

This might be little troublesome to set. There is an easier approach.

**Alternative**:

Java Server side login logic is same except the fact that now the token is added as query parameter.

Something like:

```
www.SiteB.com/autologin?Token=ldkasjodauh21i7ds8yuh
```

You can directly add it as `href` on your redirection link.

Set your AngularJS application to get the token from URL and make an API call to your nodejs server or Java Server for verification of Token.

```
var token = $location.search().token;
var isValid = false;
// You check logic here
if(isValid){// If Valid redirect to SiteB
    $location.url('http://www.siteB.com'); //$location.path('/') can be used as well
}else{//If not Valid redirect back to SiteA
    $window.location.href ='http://www.siteA.com';
}
```

**Java Server Example**

```
package app.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ResponseRedirectionServlet extends HttpServlet
{
  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException
  {
    String url = 'http://www.siteB.com';
    response.setHeader("token", "kjsydis9d979as8dh87"); //some value that your server is generating

    response.sendRedirect(url);
  }
}
```

I still have no idea about the kind of server that you are using at your SiteA. If you can provide more information about the kind of server you are using at the siteA, I'll be able to help you more precisely.

Comment: Hi. Thanks! The 2nd approach will not be viable as tokens should not be appeneded to the url for security concerns. If user copies this and paste it to another user then userb will be using site b as usera. I will look into the other approach.

Comment: Yes.. But google do it anyways :P Whenever you login through google APIs.. you can see the token ^^ facebook as well XD But you can pick any approach you like to :P I provided both so you can have more approaches to try

Comment: Hi @Hianshu Bansai. We got it to work all the way to the re-direct, but we have a problem whereby SiteB doesn't have any unique key to identify who is the user that was re-directed as the Token isn't sent during the last redirect. 

In your example you sent a request for a WS to SiteB and SiteB provides a response with the correct redirect site if token is valid.

As SiteA finally redirects to SiteB, we are unable to send any unique key to SiteB. How should we handle this?

Comment: @AlexSim my name please :D... anyways I updated the answer..please have a look :)

Comment: Hi @Himanshu Bansal, Apologies on the name mistake on my part! Must have typed it in a rush. 

Thanks for your update. I assumed you have update the url parameter part.

We are using WebSphere server for the Java Project.

Right now we have managed to do the redirection to SiteB, but the redirection is unable to identify who is the user being redirected. We do not want the information to be passed through the URL... That's the constraint we are facing. If it's on the URL we can easily do it.

Is there any way to go into a chat? :)

Comment: @AlexSim join the chatroom https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168272/rocketscience

Answer (score 1):

You can use JWT to create authorization token. It shoud be sent in redirection from site A. After that you shoud create session on site B.

Answer (score 0):

Single Sign On is a possibility, where you have an identify server that communicates with your two very different sites. There're several possibilities, a common possibility is the SAML technology. Others include CAS and OAuth.

Please search the terms on Google or/and Stackoverflow. Since you have **direct control** over the two sites, you **don't have** to use SSO if there's something simpler. @newman's answer might work.

SSO might be better if you want to integrate with external applications, which might or might not be important for you. Please think about your problem before proceeding.